# Why switching between two Tasks does not update file edited in these Tasks? What is Task in PhpStorm about?

Tags: phpstorm

These are steps I did:

- open task 1 (create branch from master, create changelist)
- do some edit in thefile
- open task 2 (create branch from master, create changelist)
- do some edit in thefile
- switching to task 1 and thefile contain edits made in task 2

So content of thefile is always the same in both tasks.

Why switching between two Tasks does not update file edited in these Tasks? What is Task in PhpStorm about?

Comment: Few links (you should find your answer there): 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Integration+with+an+Issue+Tracking+System+in+PhpStorm 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/managing-tasks-and-context.html 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/changelist.html

Comment: @LazyOne my puzzlement stems from a misunderstanding of git (switching branches without commit changes)